# Adding to a list from another class

Tags: list, class, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add the instance of an object that I click on to a list on my control object. However when I do so it says that the reference is not set to an instance of an object. The code I have to instantiate the list on the control object is:

```
public List<Transform> selected = new List<Transform>();
```

And I tried to add to it to that list using this code attached to the unit:

```
if (!selected)
    {

       // Set selected state

       selected = true;

       // Add to Selected List

       control.GetComponent<ForwardCommandScript>().selected.Add(this.transform);

       // Set material colour brighter

       oldColour = gameObject.renderer.material.color;

       newColour = oldColour + new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);

       gameObject.renderer.material.color = newColour;

    }
```

I have tried with transform as well. Later I will try to remove it by finding a reference id that was set when the unit is instantiated so should I try to add the script instead of the object if I need to find its variables and then delete the game object attached to the script. I have tried with the GameObject, transform and the class. I wanted to use the class so I can easily access the variables. I have posted this on unity answers and forums but no one replied in the week it was up and I don't like reposting the same stuff on the same site.

Cheers, Scobbo

Comment: can you copy/paste the exact error message you get and also double click the error message in unity(this will show you the line in mono which produces the error) and post where it gets you.

Comment: could you add the exact error message?

Comment: Error Message is: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SelectionScript.Select () (at Assets/Game/Scripts/Control/SelectionScript.cs:29)
SelectionScript.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Game/Scripts/Control/SelectionScript.cs:14)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32, Int32)

Comment: The line that it is failing at is: control.GetComponent<ForwardCommandScript>().selected.Add(this.transform);
I actually split this line up and it seems to be refering to the final part "selected.Add(this.transform);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` states that something in the associated line is `null`. Since the error message doesn't state which part is `null`, you have to split your code up and check which part is failing.

I'm not sure how you split it up, but try it this way:

```cs
var script = control.GetComponent<ForwardCommandScript>();
if (script == null) Debug.Log("script not found");
if (script.selected == null) Debug.Log("selected is null");
script.selected.Add(this.transform);
```

Now you should get one of the two messages in your debug log before the exception raises. Either the script was not found and you have to check if it is correctly assigned to the game object and if `control` is the correct game object, or `selected` is `null` which should not happen if you initialized it like you posted...

Comment: Well I'm an idiot, I just found I put the script it was looking for on the wrong object. But because you were helping me run through the diag for it I will choose your solution. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the complete Error Message :)

you need to replace

```
control.GetComponent<ForwardCommandScript>().selected.Add(this.transform);
```

with

```
control.GetComponent<ForwardCommandScript>().selected.Add(transform);
```

because

```
this
```

is a reference to the script and not the GameObject. you could also use gameObject.transform which transform is just an abbreviation for

Comment: this is not true and would not explain the `NullReferenceException`. Even if `this.transform` would somehow be `null` it wouldn't be a problem since you can add add `null` to a `List` without any problems.

Comment: this.transform does in fact refer to the transform attached to the script. Just saying transform finds nothing.